# Changing from dynamic memory to static memory

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I'm trying to change a dynamic memory object to static memory use to hopefully free up memory in a way.

Original code(dynamic):

Class.h:

```
Class() {
  auto output = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(new uint8_t[size]);

  Call(output.get());
  memcpy(randomlocation, output.get(), size);
}

Call(Byte *dest) {
  doStuff..
}
```

I'm very confused how I can do a similar .get() but with a non unique-ptr. I've seen `&*` may work but haven't had any luck.

My trial of static:

Class.h:

```
uint8_t *output[64];

Class() {
  Call(reinterpret_cast<Byte*>(&*output));
}
```

I have tried other ways like no `&*` and different ways of casts and haven't had any luck. It compiles sometimes, but doesn't seem to work right. **Wanting to see if this **part** is wrong, if not then I will at least know I'm doing this part right.**

Comment: It is not a C code.

Comment: What is `Byte`? Does passing just `output` not work?

Comment: ***I'm trying to change a dynamic memory object to static memory use to hopefully free up memory in a way.*** Remember that static memory is usually much more limited than dynamic memory. Normally you only have access to a small number of MB of static memory while dynamic memory has a much higher limitation.

Comment: Why? What is actual problem? This smells like [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why your attempt is `uint8_t *output[64];` not `Byte output[64];` or better `std::array<Byte, 64> output;`? Note global state usually means fragile code.

Comment: `uint8_t *output[64];` -- This declares an array of 64 *pointers*.  Is this your intention?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thanks for all the help. I really thought I had it wrong above. The [size] I was filling was not big enough for what I was putting into it. And it ended up not filling it at all and didn't throw errors to help. So that's good to know.

Comment: Side note: Rather than a `unique_ptr` to an array, consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: Note having to use "reinterpret_cast" is almost always wrong when pointers are involved. And `memcpy` is kind of a legacy "C" thing,  in C++ it is best replaced with `std::copy`

Comment: @bilumer Note that the `output` buffer is not actually needed to begin with. Since the "random address" must point to memory that is at least 64 bytes in size otherwise `memcpy()` would fail, then you could just pass the "random address" directly to the `Call()` function, eg: `Call((Byte*)randomlocation);`

Comment: Instead of `uint8_t *output[64]`, I think you meant to write `uint8_t output[64]`.  You want an array of 64 bytes right?

Comment: You should grab a book and read up on C++ - cause what you are writing shows that you do not know what memory, addresses, pointers, values, array, or casts even are.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your answer, it made my code work at least, looking more at that!

Answer (score 1):

Use `uint8_t output[64];` instead. The output is like `uint8_t*` to 64 bytes of static memory.

This works:

```
void cal(uint8_t* dest)
{
    ...
}

uint8_t output[64];    
cal(output);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).